# While solving the equation, why does it show an error for one variable 'a'?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

We have to solve a simple equation using C where the values of the variables are already given as

```
a = 2, b = 3, c = 4
```

the equation is:

```
a + b *= c - +5
```

I am getting an error message as "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

I had tried to put the equation equal to some new variable such as `x` and then I was trying to find the answer. Even if I am removing `a` variable from the equation it does not show any error and gives the output.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please don't use screenshot to share text.   Paste the text in directly

Comment: @ikegami can't we write in some other way to get the result?

Comment: @Daniel Farrell, They did. The text of the screenshot is already present in the question

Comment: Write what? Again, you haven't told us what you are trying to do

Comment: @DanielFarrell Sorry i am just a beginner, will keep this in mind from next time.

Comment: @ikegami I have to find the solution of this equation so is it possible to find the soution?

Comment: That expression is not valid. It doesn't have a "solution". What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you think `*=` does?

Comment: You haven't shown any "equation" which can be understood by readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but `*=` doesn't appear to do what you think it does.

`*=` is an assignment operator. It evaluates its left-hand side and its right-hand side, multiplies them together, and assigns the result to the result of its left-hand side.

The result of `a + b` is not something to which you can assign. This is not valid code.